# How to change Laravel crudbooster datamodal to a select2

Tags: laravel-5, jquery-select2, crud

The below code works and I can create a measurement modal that displays the kgs, grams etc but was wondering if there is a way to do it as a dropdown select2 instead as the list is quite short. the two I've tried below show just the label but no select2 box. Any ideas? regards

```
$columns = [];
        $columns[] = ['label'=>'Quantity','name'=>'quantity','type'=>'number','required'=>true];
        $columns[] = ['label'=>'Measure','name'=>'measures_id','type'=>'select2','datatable'=>'measures,measure'];
        $columns[] = ['label'=>'Measure2','name'=>'measures_id','type'=>'select2','validation'=>'required|integer|min:0','width'=>'col-sm-5','datatable'=>'measures,measure'];
        //  $columns[] = ['label'=>'Measure','name'=>'measures_id','type'=>'datamodal','datamodal_table'=>'measures','datamodal_columns'=>'measure','datamodal_select_to'=>'measure:measure','required'=>true];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do it by changing select2 to select.Not sure what the difference is.

From:

```
$columns[] = ['label'=>'Measure','name'=>'measures_id','type'=>'select2','datatable'=>'measures,measure'];
```

to:

```
$columns[] = ['label'=>'Measure','name'=>'measures_id','type'=>'select','datatable'=>'measures,measure'];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Since I cannot comment I'll suggest you the difference by adding an aswer.

The difference is:

**Select** : Standard HTML element, rendered by the browser and working according to its own code.

**Select2**: Select2 is a jQuery library that "improves" your select elements by adding HTML code to render options and adding functions. For example, you may add a search box to filter your options, or you can style the dropdown better.

Library url : [select2.org](https://select2.org/)